# har file issue browsermob-proxy with webdriverio

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, har, browsermob-proxy

I was trying to use browsermob-proxy using [this](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/328) and [this](https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node) with webdriverio. It runs fine , but theres no `har` file generated. I tried changing the below line

```
fs.writeFileSync('stuff.har', data, 'utf8');
```

to

```
fs.writeFile('/Users/abc/xyz/stuff.har', data, 'utf8');
```

in the below code (from above links)

```
   var Proxy = require('browsermob-proxy').Proxy
    , webdriverio = require("./node_modules/webdriverio/")
    , fs = require('fs')
    , proxy = new Proxy()
;
proxy.cbHAR('search.yahoo.com', doSeleniumStuff, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('ERR: ' + err);
        } else {
            fs.writeFileSync('stuff.har', data, 'utf8');

        }
});

function doSeleniumStuff(proxy, cb) {
    var browser = webdriverio.remote({
        host: 'localhost'
        , port: 4444
        , desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'firefox', seleniumProtocol: 'WebDriver', proxy: { httpProxy: proxy } }
    });

    browser
        .init()
        .url("http://search.yahoo.com")
        .setValue("#yschsp", "javascript")
        .submitForm("#sf")
        .end(cb);
}
```

but still no `har` file at the location is generated. What is missing here?

Comment: Have you tried adding a console.log message to check that `cbHAR()` ever gets called? My suspicion is that it does but that the program exits before HAR generation / writing completes.

Comment: @AndrewRegan Thanks. I try adding `console.log` inside `cbHAR()` and doSeleniumStuff(). I dont see on console , the one inside `cbHAR`. So seems code inside `cbHAR()` does not get executed. I am new to this and `node.js` in general and not sure how to debug more. Do you see anything obviously missing in code?

Comment: Presumably `doSeleniumStuff` does get called within `cbHAR`, as you say this works, it's just that the callback doesn't get called? Looking at the source (https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node/blob/310490298b565a431b93471e0d93096e00650cda/index.js#L51) it really looks like it ought to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to run the below code to generate the har file. Note minor change to  `doSeleniumStuff` function from `.end(cb);` to `.end().then(cb);`

```
var Proxy = require('browsermob-proxy').Proxy
    , webdriverio = require("./node_modules/webdriverio/")
    , fs = require('fs')
    , proxy = new Proxy()
;

proxy.cbHAR('search.yahoo.com', doSeleniumStuff, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {

            console.error('ERR: ' + err);
        } else {

            fs.writeFileSync('stuff.har', data, 'utf8');
            //fs.writeFile('/Users/hanu/Desktop/amit/webdriverio/webdriverio-test/stuff.har', data, 'utf8');

        }
});

function doSeleniumStuff(proxy, cb) {

    var browser = webdriverio.remote({
        host: 'localhost'
        , port: 4444
        , desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'firefox', seleniumProtocol: 'WebDriver', proxy: { httpProxy: proxy } }
    });

    browser
        .init()
        .url("http://search.yahoo.com")
        .setValue("#yschsp", "javascript")
        .submitForm("#sf")
        .end().then(cb);        

}
```